# columns unnecessarily skip a page in ConTeXt

Tags: tikz-pgf, page-breaking, context

I have block-level commands that enclose some content with horizontal rules drawn with tikz. It works well most of the time, but when I use it exactly at the position of a page break, and the content is a `columns` environment, ConTeXt generates an almost blank page. Here is an MCVE:

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\usetikzlibrary[positioning,fit,calc]

\definestartstop[Solution][before={
  \blank[0.5em,preference]
  \starttikzpicture
    \node[rectangle,draw=black,anchor=north west] (header) {\bfxx\ss Sample Solution};
    \draw[line cap=rect,draw=black] (header.north east) ++(0,-\pgflinewidth/2) -- (\textwidth-\pgflinewidth,-\pgflinewidth/2);
  \stoptikzpicture
  \blank[0.5em,samepage]
},after={
  \blank[0.125em,samepage]
  \starttikzpicture
    \draw[black] (0,0) -- (\textwidth-\pgflinewidth,0) -- ++(0,0.25cm);
  \stoptikzpicture
}]

\starttext
  \dontleavehmode \vfill
  \blank[26.5cm]

  Lorem Ipsum

  \startSolution
    \startcolumns[n=2]
      \input Knuth
    \stopcolumns
  \stopSolution
\stoptext
```

The generated PDF looks like this:

#### Pages 1 & 2

[image]

#### Page 3

[image]

As you can see, ConTeXt shifts the whole `columns` block to the third page although there is plenty of space on the second page (which is left completely blank).

From my tests, it seems like the problem comes from the interaction of tikz and columns; if I remove the columns, the content is put on the second page; same if I replace the tikz lines with normal `\hrule`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Replace `\startcolumn` with `\startsimplecolumn`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is unrelated to TikZ. Here is a simpler example showing the same behavior:

```
\starttext
  \dontleavehmode \vfill
  \blank[26.5cm]

  Lorem Ipsum

  \vbox to \lineheight{Solution}

  \startcolumns[n=2]
    \input knuth
  \stopcolumns
\stoptext
```

The reason that you get a page break is that, during the initialization, `\startcolumn` uses:

```
   \ifdim\dimexpr\pagetotal+\parskip+\openlineheight\relax<\pagegoal
     \allowbreak
   \else
     \break 
   \fi
```

Adding that to a test document shows that we get the same behavior:

```
\starttext
  \dontleavehmode \vfill
  \blank[26.5cm]

  Lorem Ipsum

  \vbox to \lineheight{Solution}

   \ifdim\dimexpr\pagetotal+\parskip+\openlineheight\relax<\pagegoal
     \message{YES}%
     \allowbreak
   \else
      \message{NO}%
     \break 
   \fi

    \input knuth
\stoptext
```

The output shows `NO`, which means that `\break` is being inserted (instead of `\allowbreak`).

I haven't tested further, but my guess is that the following is happening. ConTeXt (rather TeX) reads the `\startcolumn` code while still on the first page. It then does the check for the space remaining on the page, and inserts a `\break`. Now when the actual typesetting is being done, you get a pagebreak after `Solution` due to the `\break`.

In the following two examples, I insert a `\page` before the `\vbox` (to force TeX to eject the previous page) and everything works fine:

Simple example:

```
\starttext
  \dontleavehmode \vfill
  \blank[26.5cm]

  Lorem Ipsum

  \page

  \vbox to \lineheight{Solution}

   \ifdim\dimexpr\pagetotal+\parskip+\openlineheight\relax<\pagegoal
     \message{YES}%
     \allowbreak
   \else
      \message{NO}%
     \break 
   \fi

    \input knuth
\stoptext
```

Original example:

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\usetikzlibrary[positioning,fit,calc]

\definestartstop[Solution][before={
  \blank[0.5em,preference]
  \starttikzpicture
    \node[rectangle,draw=black,anchor=north west] (header) {\bfxx\ss Sample Solution};
    \draw[line cap=rect,draw=black] (header.north east) ++(0,-\pgflinewidth/2) -- (\textwidth-\pgflinewidth,-\pgflinewidth/2);
  \stoptikzpicture
  \blank[0.5em,samepage]
},after={
  \blank[0.125em,samepage]
  \starttikzpicture
    \draw[black] (0,0) -- (\textwidth-\pgflinewidth,0) -- ++(0,0.25cm);
  \stoptikzpicture
}]

\starttext
  \dontleavehmode \vfill
  \blank[26.5cm]

  Lorem Ipsum

  \page

  \startSolution
    \startcolumns[n=2]
      \input Knuth
    \stopcolumns
  \stopSolution
\stoptext
```

### Workaround 1

Now that we know what is happening, it is simple to find a workaround. The first workaround is to simply add a page break if there isn't enough space on the page. This can be done using `\testpagesync[n]` which forces a page break if there is not enough space to fit `n` lines in the page:

```
\definestartstop[Solution][before={
  \testpagesync[5]
  \blank[0.5em,preference]
  \starttikzpicture
    \node[rectangle,draw=black,anchor=north west] (header) {\bfxx\ss Sample Solution};
    \draw[line cap=rect,draw=black] (header.north east) ++(0,-\pgflinewidth/2) -- (\textwidth-\pgflinewidth,-\pgflinewidth/2);
  \stoptikzpicture
  \blank[0.5em,samepage]
},after={
  \blank[0.125em,samepage]
  \starttikzpicture
    \draw[black] (0,0) -- (\textwidth-\pgflinewidth,0) -- ++(0,0.25cm);
  \stoptikzpicture
}]
```

### Workaround 2

The other workaround is to use `\startsimplecolumns ... \stopsimplecolumns` instead of `\startcolumns ... \stopcolumns`. As the name suggests, `simplecolumns` are meant for, well, simple columns. So, they don't handle floats, etc. Depending on the usage, that might be sufficient.

Comment: Using `\startsimplecolumns` in my actual document yielded a `You can't use '\end' in internal vertical mode`, so I went with `\testpagesync`. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: @flyx: Could you post a minimal example showing the error?

Comment: Since the other workaround worked, I moved on with that. I could try and produce a minimal example for the error, but unless you have a specific reason to debug it, I don't think it's worth the time.